# Put a photo to the bottom of other photo using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to html and bootstrap and I need a little help. I have a photo with 100% in a div col-lg-12 and I want to put another div with a photo, in the left, and a paragraph, in the right.

The second div I want to be in the bottom of the first picture and centered. How I made the html and bootstrap the second div comes after the picture ends. I want the whole high of the sec div to be in bottom of picture not after the picture ends.

I tried with position absolute but doesn't work to be responsive. Please someone give me an idea.

HTML

```
<div class="container main-container">  
<div class=" top">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <img src="images/header.jpg" alt="#" />

            <div class="row">   
                <div class="photo col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <img src="images/best_friends_logo.png" alt="#" />
                </div>
                <div class="info col-lg-8">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur luctus velit nec sagittis mattis. Sed et tellus blandit turpis vulputate eleifend. </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each section of vertical contents, you will have to create a new `row`.

Your code should be something like this. To make things clear from the demo, I'm replacing `lg` with `xs`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/2048x128" alt="#" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="photo col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/512x1024" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="info col-xs-8">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur luctus velit nec sagittis mattis. Sed et tellus blandit turpis vulputate eleifend. </h1>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<div class="container main-container">  
<div class=" top">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="images/header.jpg" alt="#" />
        </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12">   
                <div class="photo col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <img src="images/best_friends_logo.png" alt="#" />
                </div>
                <div class="info col-lg-8">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur luctus velit nec sagittis mattis. Sed et tellus blandit turpis vulputate eleifend. </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```